# How to use NVL function between case statements?

Tags: vertica

I have multiple case statements  like below

> MAX(CASE When id = 'a' then value else null)

I want to use NVL function to display that if it is null display as '0'.

how can i do this?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can use the same way in vertica also.

```
NVL(MAX(CASE When id = 'a' then value else null),0)
```

For more detatils refer to this [link](https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.1.6/HTML/index.htm#10435.htm).